# What is the fastest way to iterate over a numpy array elements?

Tags: python, numpy, geopy

I have a NumPy array of float distance values such as D, and I need to apply geodesic function from geopy python library on each element of the numpy array. I have done it successfully using for loop iterations, but it is too slow as D size sometimes gets larger than 3000 elements. Is there any way we can use vectorization or another faster method rather than for loop to apply functions on every single element of a NumPy array? something like this:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic

lat_start = 48.778767
long_start = -123.903275
bearing = 39.060744
coords1=(lat_start,long_start)
D = array([  0.        ,  60.00501526, 120.01003051, 180.01504577,
       240.02006102, 300.02507628, 360.03009153, 420.03510679,
       480.04012205, 540.0451373 ])
destination = geodesic(kilometers= D/ 1000).destination(coords1, bearing)
```

Comment: I recommend pyproj, here you go https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html?highlight=transformer#pyproj.transformer.Transformer

Comment: since you are not specifying which CRS you are using it is difficult to write a concrete code example. Is your original (lat,lon) in WGS84? Why do you need a bearing? What is D? What does geodesic do exactly?

Comment: "vectorization" in `numpy` usually means performing the iterations in compiled numpy methods.  In other words, moving the iterations from slow interpreted python to compiled c code.  If you must iterate in python, stick with lists.

Comment: @sehan2, CRS is WGS84, basically, I am going to calculate latitude and longitude for multiple points knowing the original point (coords1), bearing (direction), and distance. D is an array of all distances.

Comment: ok, thanks. So from your code I presume your furthest distance D is slightly more than 500 meters, right? If that is the case why are you not using a Cartesian projection? That could simplify your computation significantly?

Comment: I have tried it but it is not accurate. Sometimes the distance is more than a few kilometers.